# Creating documents on behalf of companies who subsequently sign/stamp the document (UK Visa)

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

My wife and I are in Japan, moving back to the UK.

I'm preparing everything for moving, and finding it harder and harder to get Japanese companies to provide what we need.

To prove my partner and I are living together I'm providing:

Marriage Certificate (original & translated),
Photos of us together, the ceremony we had (small)

In addition to this, our landlord agency have stated that they cannot provide any evidence to show that my wife and I have been living together.

The tenancy agreement is a huge messy contract in Japanese, that has both names, but would cost a fortune to translate into English.

They have stated that I can create a document in English, that they will have someone review, stamp/sign to validate the document. In Japan, stamps are much more authoritative then signatures.

Is this sufficient as evidence?

My concern is, I find myself doing this for a number of people to just 'Sign off' and its worrying me that it will all end up being useless.

Comment: So long as a proper translator approves your translation why would it be considered any different than if they actually did the translation?

Comment: @LorenPechtel  Its not a translation. It's a document in English I'm creating from scratch.

Comment: Are you a British citizen? Does it matter whether you and your wife have lived together? That requirement exists only for unregistered partners AFAIK, and for those suspected of a marriage or partnership of convenience. If you were married some time ago, it's probably entirely unnecessary.

Comment: @phoog We've only been married since June this year, she has my last name. Do you think that's enough?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I guess you might indeed need evidence that your marriage is genuine since its been just six months or so. I don't know how important evidence of cohabitation would be, though I suspect it's not critical. Photos and communications records might be sufficient (e-mail messages, etc.). With regard to your actual question, the signature or stamp indicates that the signer stands by the contents of the document, not that he or she wrote or prepared it. It's common to prepare documents for others' signatures.

Comment: A tenancy agreement can be used to show cohabitation, which in turn corroborates a claim to genuine marriage. But certainly it's not a requirement. The vicissitudes of life create situations where couples can and do live separately prior to emigrating to the UK or do not have tenancy agreements (e.g., living with the bride's parents, etc).  If you do not have one or it's too cumbersome to translate, don't include it.

Comment: @GayotFow We've got photos of us together at home. The problem is, when you live together, you don't have Skype logs/Emails/Etc. because we're together all the time.

I'll probably try to provide some text logs of WhatsApp, but we talk on that whilst I'm working EVERYDAY. So, it almost overkill

Comment: It seems you are approaching it ass-about-face, are you reading lots of random immigration forums where random people are discussing tenancy agreements? Please go back to your original question and EDIT to include why you think there's a reason for UKVI to suspect a sham marriage. It will help us to understand if you are overthinking this issue about tenancy agreements or not. Thanks!

Comment: @GayotFow Sorry, I am overthinking it. There's nothing about our marriage that would indicate its a sham. I think a lot of it is just ticking all the boxes the first time. Everything we have ticks all the boxes. My original question stands, if I write a letter in English on behalf of the agency stating that we both lived together, as long as they sign and stamp it to verify the contents, would this be sufficient as evidence? The follow up comments are purely my mind wondering. My understanding was, a tenancy agreement or validation that we love together would help further solidify things.

Comment: Yes, you can prepare an attestation for the landlord to sign, but it can be a double-edged sword. And remember that all they really need to see is the marriage certificate and voluntarily anything implicit or explicit that you and your wife are 'intimate'.  Remember that Brit/Japanese couples do not have the credibility problems like Brit/Tunisia couples for example.